# How to display Toast message in windows phone?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I am new to windows phone development. I need to display the Toast message for 3 seconds. 
I have tried with code below

```
ShellToast toast = new ShellToast();
        toast.Title = "My title";
        toast.Content = " my message";
        toast.Show();
```

It is not working for me. How to solve this ?

Comment: How are you running this? Is it in background agent? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

you could use the [Coding 4 fun library](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) this has a ToastPromt and is very easy to use!